# Java's HashMap collision resolution

Tags: java, hashmap

So from what I've read on stackoverflow and other websites. Java uses linkedlists for hash collision resolution.

This would guarantee a O(n) complexity for worst case scenarios of inserting, getting and, removing.

Why does Java not use a self balancing BST (Like AVL, Red Black, etc...) to guarantee a O(log n) complexity for worst case scenarios of inserting, getting, and, removing?

Comment: Surprise: Java 8 uses a balanced tree for collisions: http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2016/01/how-does-java-hashmap-or-linkedhahsmap-handles.html?m=1

Comment: The main reason is that `HashMap` doesn't require its element type to be `Comparable`. But the new Java 8 implementation will check at runtime whether the element is comparable and use a balanced tree if it is. This is quite tricky (just because an element is comparable against its own type doesn't mean it's comparable against all other key types in the HashMap) - probably why this wasn't done earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time there's going to be a very small number of items in a bucket; often zero or one.  In these cases, a simple hash bucket structure is able to guarantee O(1); an O(log n) BST might cut off time in some sub-optimal edge cases, but the performance gain is negligible at best and negative at worst.  There's also significant memory overhead.  Java 8 does make an effort to detect when a linked list is no longer optimal and convert to a BST; however, if this behavior occurs frequently, it's a sign that hashes and HashMap are being used incorrectly.

There are a lot of implementation details available when reading the source code for the JDK.  Here's a brief excerpt from the top of Oracle's java.util.HashMap:

```
/*
 * Implementation notes.
 *
 * This map usually acts as a binned (bucketed) hash table, but
 * when bins get too large, they are transformed into bins of
 * TreeNodes, each structured similarly to those in
 * java.util.TreeMap. Most methods try to use normal bins, but
 * relay to TreeNode methods when applicable (simply by checking
 * instanceof a node).  Bins of TreeNodes may be traversed and
 * used like any others, but additionally support faster lookup
 * when overpopulated. However, since the vast majority of bins in
 * normal use are not overpopulated, checking for existence of
 * tree bins may be delayed in the course of table methods.
 * [...]
```

Looking at the implementations of HashMap#getNode and HashMap.Node, we can see that each bucket starts as a very simple linked list--simpler than java.util.LinkedList, which is actually a doubly-linked list.

Per the comment, when a list grows to a certain size, it's converted to a tree.  It's hard to tell exactly what's going on in HashMap.TreeNode because the code isn't exactly self-descriptive, but it appears to be a simple red-black BST.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was looking at Java 7 and older comments. :)

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 *does,* if a linked chain gets big enough.

For small numbers of elements, though, it adds significant memory and performance overhead.  A linked list is really extremely efficient for very small numbers of elements, which are exactly what you expect for hash buckets in 99% of situations.  Additionally, defining how, exactly, the binary tree should be sorted is non-obvious, and has to special-case when the elements are `Comparable`, sorting by the unused hash code bits...it gets hairy.

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't thought that deeply about it. Thanks that makes perfect sense now!